# Population of python GUI isn’t matching

Tags: python, user-interface

I’ve made a GUI in python.
When I populate it, and run the file, the values are one off.
For example:
Title: James
Name: 12
Age: Australia
etc..

The population file is all correct so not sure how to fix it!!

Comment: Can you extend what did you done and what is the problem?

Comment: I have created a GUI using python. I have tried to popular it, but when I run the file and use the GUI, the values don’t correspond correctly! the population file is correct though

Comment: Nobody cant produce a solution unless you tell us how did you do it

Comment: You need to show the code where you load the data and assign it to the fields in the interface. It is likely that you are doing some tuple unpacking and have the left hand side where the first field isn't first and something else is taking the title.